# Magento Dashboard Displaying Different figure in lifetime sales and revenue, is that usual process or having some problem?

Tags: magento-1

My Magento Site's Dashboard Displaying Different figure in lifetime sales and revenue, is that usual process or it has some problem?

I have no idea whether it has a problem or it is the usual thing as I have seen other site and it is showing the same different figure.

Anyone with the knowledge of Magento dashboard and revenue??

I am using magento-1.5.1.0

Comment: Just to check the easy stuff first, have you tried re-indexing the site? If so, how about going under "Reports" > Refresh Statistics and refreshing lifetime statistics for all of them?

Comment: Thanks Mike for reply. Yes i have refreshed the statistics many times, what i want is ,can these figures differs usually in all sites or different figure of lifetime sales and revenue is a problem?

Comment: @sonassi : yes it is duplicated as i am not getting the answer, that question is asked by my friends

Comment: I did it with changing the configuration like following:
Go to System → Config → Sales → Sale → Dashboard And mark 
Use Aggregated Data (beta)="Yes"